# Using margin in @media

Tags: html, css

I have some css which is perfect in mobile but I'm trying make work in desktop `@media min-width 768px`. I'm trying to get two pieces of text closer together and moved down the page around `50px`. Whatever I try though, I can't seem to move it.

Here it is, and what I want to move is *find an event* and *post an event*.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .event_wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1 fr 1 fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'a b c d e f';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lasvegas">Events</div>
<div class="findanevent" />
<div class="event_wrapper">
  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">
    <span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span>.
  </a>
  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">
    <span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space before `fr` unit:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: What exactly should i remove please?

Comment: The line beginning with grid-template-columns? Ending 1fr?